# multiline alignment of equals signs with warping long lines?

Tags: amsmath

Can someone please tell me how to align a multiline equation to the left of my page, aligning the elements of each line on the equals sign. Further, warping long lines so that they do not come under the equals signs?

Below is what I'm trying to align and warp.

```
\begin{multline*}
T = R \cap S
T = \{ (a \mapsto 6), (b \mapsto 5), (c \mapsto 4), (d \mapsto 3), (e \mapsto 2), (f \mapsto 1), (g \mapsto 0) \cap\\
\{ a \mapsto 6), (b \mapsto 3), (c \mapsto 2), (d \mapsto 1) \} \}\\ 
\end{multline*}
```

I have read several articles on this stack prior to posting this. None of them have helped. Some of them enabled me to set alignment around the equals sign, but when this happened everything aligned to the centre of the page as well. I seem to be spending more time on figuring out alignment than I am on doing math!  Help is really appreciated.

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

`multline` is for a single unaligned wrapped equation. You want `align` to specify alignment points.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
T &= R \cap S\\
T &= \begin{aligned}[t]
&\{ (a \mapsto 6), (b \mapsto 5), (c \mapsto 4), (d \mapsto 3),\\
&\quad (e \mapsto 2), (f \mapsto 1), (g \mapsto 0) \cap{}\\
&\quad \{ a \mapsto 6), (b \mapsto 3), (c \mapsto 2), (d \mapsto 1) \} \}
          \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

As tyou provided no test document I wrapped to an arbitrary width as you gave no hint of the column width.

Comment: Thank you so much!